# redirect from mysite.com to www.mysite.com

Tags: domain, redirect, flash, url-routing

i know that this has been answered many many times, so if someone wants to point me to another thread that answers my question specifically, that is fine... for right now, my searches aren't yielding many results.

so i have a website like
mysite.com
that has a flash swf embedded in it
and i go to
www.mysite.com
... all of the sudden, things don't work properly.
i would like to get to the bottom of this, because it's not like the page just "doesn't load" at all; it loads and i can only do certain things; as if certain functionality is disabled (might be url requests for specific urls etc).

do i need to manage this in my control panel?
i wouldn't assume so, because the site loads; just has a crippled functionality from within the swf.

i was thinking it might have more to do with my crossdomain.xml file; could this be the case?

thanks for any tips or suggestions.

Comment: Please give more details about your setup. Linux? Windows? Apache? IIS?

Comment: os x; apache; flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it turned out that i was issuing a request for the wrong URL.  sorry for the noise.
i made a req to mysite.com/some/url instead of www.mysite.com/some/url

:p

Comment: relative URLs are your best friend!

Answer (score 1):

I think this will get you what you need in most cases.

You can add this to your .htaccess file on the server.

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !^www\.example\.net$       [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://www.example.net/$1  [L,R]
```

I got it from my web hosts [wiki](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Requiring_%22www%22_for_your_web_site)

Answer (score 0):

Theres a huge Wiki article on this here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection

Instead of turning on Rewrite engine a simple html file like:

```
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://www.example.com/">
</head><body>
 <p>Please follow <a href="http://www.example.com/">link</a>!</p>
</body></html>
```

will solve your problem without having to engage more code.